# unexplained linux case insensitivity in standard filename expansion

Tags: bash, glob, case-sensitive

I do not understand. How is this matching?

```
$: shopt nocaseglob
nocaseglob      off
$: printf "%s\n" parser/*[a-z].jar
parser/parser-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar
parser/parser.jar
```

It's a VM in a cluster, not an emulation on a Windows machine.

```
$: cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

I'm trying to do a simple case-sensitive match to *exclude* anything that isn't a lowercase alpha in front of `.jar`. I just want the version-anonymized symlinks for a loop, not the actual versioned files.

Comment: What type of filesystem are you using?

Comment: What is your `locale` setting?

Comment: It's valid for en_US locale https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227070/why-does-a-z-match-lowercase-letters-in-bash

Comment: Use `[[:lower:]]` to avoid locale-specific range issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What `[a-z]` matches depends on the current `locale`. Under `LC_COLLATE=C`, `[a-z]` matches `[abcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz]`, but under some other settings, e.g. `en_US`, it matches `[aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYz]` - note that `Z` is not matched.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: That's how the locales are defined. Probably because someone thought/decided that's the way English speaking people in the US sort words.